# Why onlick function return this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

```
let classMessage = document.createElement('class');
document.getElementById("chat").prepend(classMessage);
classMessage.id = tabMsg[0];
classMessage.innerHTML += '<button onclick="del(' + tabMsg[0] + ')">Try it</button>'

function del(parsedata) {
console.log(parsedata)
}
```

tabMsg is a parsed line (with split).

i dont understand why when i click on the button the output on the console is :

```
<class id="vuwzbip6dr"><button onclick="del(vuwzbip6dr)">Try it</button><p>gfdgf gdfgf</p></class>
```

why he dont put the id vuwzbip6dr !!! ?

Comment: What is `tabMsg`? Where does that value come from?

Comment: @Pointy - presumably the char `v` from OP's comment: `//tabMsg = string (like vuwzbip6dr)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn well sure, but then the behavior reported in the question would be impossible.

Comment: @Pointy it isn't - what has happened is caused by the concatenation. It ends up calling `del(v)`, which is the same `del(eventTarget)` - so the. target prints out. I suspect that if the OP was to use the `eventTarget` property properly, he would print out the ID he wants.

Comment: @RandyCasburn i have edited my question :)

Comment: @Pointy , question edited

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulating strings with strings within strings generally causes more problems than it solves and therefore should be avoided.

In your case that means this statement:

`'<button onclick="del(' + tabMsg[0] + ')">Try it</button>'` is causing the issue for you.

That line is interpreted as:

`<button onclick="del(v)">Try it</button>`

Where `v` becomes an identifier pointing to the `this`, or the `currentTarget` element and not a string like this: "dev('v')".

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#value) one sees the `onclick` handler is provided the `currentTarget` as the first argument to the callback - hence the assignment I mention.

To fix this you should rely on the tools JavaScript provides - namely, it gives you the `currentTarget` (target element of the click), so all you have to do is use that and ask for it's parent element's id attribute:

```
classMessage.innerHTML += '<button onclick=del(this)>Try it</button>'

function del(target) {
    console.log(target.parentNode.id)
}
```

But that isn't recommended either. You should always try to avoid using in-line event handlers. I'll leave that to a different question for you.